# Five9ListsController is not a supported controller name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a controller created named `five9_lists_controller.rb`.

I want to say this work fine when it was a singular naming convention, but I changed it to plural and my test now throws this error:

```
/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:239:in 
`default_controller_and_action': 'Five9ListsController' is not a supported controller 
name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use (ArgumentError)
```

Why is that an invalid controller name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you catch the note at the very end of the Guides section you referenced?

> Only the directory notation is supported. Specifying the
>   controller with ruby constant notation (eg. `:controller =>
>   'Admin::UserPermissions'`) can lead to routing problems and results in
>   a warning.

In fact, this is exactly what's producing the message you're seeing:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L237

Try specifying the route with `controller: 'five9_lists_controller'` instead.